# Can't see Data in Favourite fragnment from Home Fragnment

Tags: java, android, database, roomdb

After clicking on the heart button the card should get saved in the Favourite fragment I am using Room Db to save the card i had made dao class and database class too I had made an insert query on the heart button too

```
package com.trycatch_tanmay.code;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.trycatch_tanmay.ModelHome;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FavouriteFragment extends Fragment implements FavouriteAdapter.OnFavoriteItemClickListener {
    private RecyclerView favoRv;
    private FavouriteAdapter favouriteAdapter;
    private List<ModelHome> favouriteList;
    private FavouriteDao favouriteDao;
    private FavouriteDatabase favouriteDatabase;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourite, container, false);
        favoRv = view.findViewById(R.id.favoRv);
        favouriteList = new ArrayList<>();
        favouriteAdapter = new FavouriteAdapter(requireContext(), favouriteList);
        favoRv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2));
        favoRv.setAdapter(favouriteAdapter);

        // Initialize the FavouriteDatabase instance
        favouriteDatabase = FavouriteDatabase.getInstance(requireContext());
        // Initialize the FavouriteDao instance
        favouriteDao = favouriteDatabase.getfavouriteDao();

        fetchData();
        return view;
    }

    private void fetchData() {
        favouriteList.clear(); // Clear previous data before fetching new data
        // Fetch data from the database
        List<ModelHome> userList = favouriteDao.getAllUsers();
        for (ModelHome modelHome : userList) {
            favouriteList.add(modelHome); // Add each retrieved item to the favouriteList
        }
        favouriteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify adapter of data change
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        fetchData(); // Refresh data when fragment resumes
    }

    @Override
    public void onFavoriteItemClick(int position) {
        // Handle item click in favourites here
        ModelHome clickedItem = favouriteList.get(position);
        // Implement your logic
    }
} this is my favourite fragnment 
package com.trycatch_tanmay.code;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.trycatch_tanmay.HomeAdapter;
import com.trycatch_tanmay.ModelHome;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements HomeAdapter.OnFavoriteItemClickListener {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private HomeAdapter homeAdapter;
    private List<ModelHome> modelHomeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private UserDao userDao;
    private FavouriteDatabase favouriteDatabase;
    private FavouriteDao favouriteDao; // Correct initialization
    FavouriteAdapter favouriteAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(requireContext(), modelHomeList,favouriteDao);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);

        // Initialize the FavouriteDatabase instance
        favouriteDatabase = FavouriteDatabase.getInstance(requireContext());
// Initialize the FavouriteDao instance
        favouriteDao = favouriteDatabase.getfavouriteDao(); // Proper initialization
        Userdatabase userDatabase = Userdatabase.getINSTANCE(requireContext());
        userDao = userDatabase.getmodel();

        fetchData();

        // Set the click listener for the HomeAdapter
        homeAdapter.setOnFavoriteItemClickListener(new HomeAdapter.OnFavoriteItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFavoriteItemClick(int position, ModelHome modelHome) {
                handleFavoriteItemClick(position, modelHome);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void fetchData() {
        homeAdapter.clearData();
        List<ModelHome> userList = userDao.getAllUsers();
        for (ModelHome modelHome : userList) {
            homeAdapter.addUser(modelHome);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        fetchData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFavoriteItemClick(int position, ModelHome modelHome) {
//        handleFavoriteItemClick(position, modelHome);
        // Handle item click in favourites here
        ModelHome clickedItem = modelHomeList.get(position);
        // Implement your logic

        // Call the Insert method to save the clickedItem to the database
        favouriteDao.Insert(clickedItem);

        // Notify the adapter of data change in the FavouriteFragment
        favouriteAdapter.addUser(clickedItem);
    }

    private void handleFavoriteItemClick(int position, ModelHome clickedItem) {
//// ADpter click listern insert query on heart button and  favourtite dao inziale favourite get all
        // Get an instance of FavouriteDao
        FavouriteDao favouriteDao = favouriteDatabase.getfavouriteDao();

        // Call the Insert method to save the clickedItem to the database
        favouriteDao.Insert(clickedItem);

        // Replace the fragment with the FavouriteFragment and pass the clicked item
        Fragment favouriteFragment = new FavouriteFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("clickedItem", clickedItem);
        favouriteFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.favourite_container, favouriteFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
this is my HomeFragnment package com.trycatch_tanmay;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.trycatch_tanmay.code.FavouriteDao;
import com.trycatch_tanmay.code.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<ModelHome> modelHomes;
    private FavouriteDao favouriteDao; // Add FavouriteDao field
    private OnFavoriteItemClickListener listener; // Corrected variable name

    public interface OnFavoriteItemClickListener {
        void onFavoriteItemClick(int position,ModelHome modelHome);
    }



    public HomeAdapter(Context context, List<ModelHome> modelHomes, FavouriteDao favouriteDao) {
        this.context = context;
        this.modelHomes = new ArrayList<>(modelHomes);
        this.favouriteDao = favouriteDao;
    }


    public void addUser(ModelHome modelHome) {
        modelHomes.add(modelHome);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearData() {
        modelHomes.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setModelHomes(List<ModelHome> modelHomes) {
        this.modelHomes = new ArrayList<>(modelHomes);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void setImageData(List<ModelHome> modelHomes) {
        this.modelHomes = new ArrayList<>(modelHomes);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    // Correcting the listener implementation
    public void setOnFavoriteItemClickListener(OnFavoriteItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HomeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.homeitemview, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ModelHome modelHome = modelHomes.get(position); // Declare as final here
        if (modelHomes.get(position).getName() != null && modelHomes.get(position).getContact() != null &&
                modelHomes.get(position).getAddress() != null && modelHomes.get(position).getPosition() != null) {
            if (modelHome.getImagePath() != null) {
                // Use Glide or Picasso to load image into the ImageView
                Glide.with(context).load(modelHome.getImagePath()).into(holder.image_1);
            }
            // Set data to views
            holder.textView1.setText("Names:" + modelHomes.get(position).getName());
            holder.textView2.setText(("Position:" + modelHome.getPosition()));
            holder.textView3.setText("Company Name:" + modelHome.getAddress());
            holder.favoriteOpt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                // Handle favourite option click
                if (favouriteDao != null) {
                    favouriteDao.Insert(modelHome); // Insert the clicked item into the database
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelHomes.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image_1, image_menu, editOpt, favoriteOpt, shareOpt;
        TextView textView1, textView2, textView3;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_1);
            image_menu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_menu);
            editOpt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editOpt);
            favoriteOpt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favoriteOpt);
            shareOpt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareOpt);
            textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

//            Set on clickOnclickListener for favouriteOpt
            favoriteOpt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onFavoriteItemClick(adapterPosition, modelHomes.get(adapterPosition));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
this is my Home adapter and perfroming on click in and called that interface in Homefragnment
```

I had put insert query on heart button and get all method is use in favorite  fragment then why it is not happeinng

Answer (score 0):

ok did u check that the DB is creating table or not in app inspection

[image]

here see its look like if data is going in and showing its mean gettting data problem in favorite fragment first check this then i will help u in next method